# The background-color isn't going to the bottom

Tags: html, css

I can't get the background color all the way down to the bottom of the page. [This is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSVpE.png). The red and the black should be on the background of the "Links Favoritos" text.

Im pretty new to HMTL and CSS, still learning.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

div.retangulo1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #50bbcf;
}

div.retangulo2 {
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  background-color: #4fcce3;
}

hgroup#hgroup1 {
  font-family: 'Arial Black', sans-serif;
  margin-left: 2%;
  color: #2d6975;
}


/* Barra Navegação */

.barraNAV {
  position: absolute;
  padding-right: 40px;
  top: 130px;
  left: 10%;
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 40px;
  background-color: #2d6975;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}


/* Primeira linha */

.linha1 {
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #2d6975;
}

li#lisNAV {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  float: left;
  color: white;
}


/* AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
   AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
   AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
   AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
   AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
   AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
   AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
   AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA */


/* Container parte principal*/

.backgroundMAIN {
  /*background-color: lightgray;*/
  background-color: black;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.main {
  /*background-color: beige;*/
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  display: inline-block;
}


/* Quem Sou */

section.QuemSou {
  float: left;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 5%;
  font-family: 'Century Gothic', sans-serif;
}

p#QuemSou {
  line-height: 30px;
}


/* Imagem */

div.divimgMAIN {
  float: right;
  /* FAZER COM QUE NÃO SE USE FLOAT: RIGHT; */
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-right: 10%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

img#imgMAIN {
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.linha2 {
  clear: both;
  width: 95%;
  margin-left: 2.5%;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: #2d6975;
}

section.Contact {
  margin-left: 5%;
  font-family: 'Century Gothic', sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}

h2#titH2 {
  font-size: 1.9em;
}

.fieldset_mensagem {
  margin-right: 9.5%;
  line-height: 35px;
}

#fieldset_input {
  width: 90%;
}

textarea {
  width: 95.5%;
  height: 100px;
}

#fieldset_enviar {
  float: right;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-right: 2%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-PT">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css">
  <title>Ficha 7 V3</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="retangulo1">
      <div class="retangulo2">
        <hgroup id="hgroup1">
          <h1>Francisco Costa</h1>
          <h2>Homepage</h2>
        </hgroup>
        <div class="barraNAV">
          <nav>
            <ul type="none">
              <li id="lisNAV">Quem Sou&emsp;|&emsp;</li>
              <li id="lisNAV">Contacte-me&emsp;|&emsp;</li>
              <li id="lisNAV">Links</li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>


  <div class="linha1"></div>


  <div class="backgroundMAIN">
    <div class="main">
      <a name="QuemSou"></a>
      <section class="QuemSou">
        <h2>Quem Sou</h2>
        <p id="QuemSou">
          <b>Nome:</b> Francisco Costa<br>
          <b>Idade:</b> 18 anos<br>
          <b>Atividade:</b> Estudante<br>
          <b>Onde vivo:</b> Santa Maria da Feira
        </p>
      </section>
      <div class="divimgMAIN">
        <img id="imgMAIN" src="./images/linus.png">
      </div>
      <div class="linha2"></div>
      <a name="Contact"></a>
      <section class="Contact">
        <h2 id="titH2">Contacte-me</h2>
        <fieldset class="fieldset_mensagem">
          <legend>A sua mensagem</legend>

          <label for="name">Nome:</label>
          <input id="fieldset_input" type="text" placeholder="Primeiro e último nome" pattern="^[A-Za-zçÇ\s]+$" required autocomplete="name">

          <label for="email">Email:</label>
          <input id="fieldset_input" type="text" placeholder="exemplo@email.pt" required autocomplete="email">

          <label for="mensagem">Mensagem:</label><br>
          <textarea id="mensagem" placeholder="Mensagem" required></textarea>

          <input id="fieldset_enviar" type="submit" value="Enviar">
        </fieldset>
      </section>

      <div class="linha2"></div>

      <h2 id="titH2">Links Favoritos</h2>

      <ul>
        <li id="linksFAV"><a href="https://www.youtube.com">Youtube</a></li>
        <li id="linksFAV"><a href="https://www.twitch.tv">Twitch</a></li>
        <li id="linksFAV"><a href="https://store.steampowered.com/?l=portuguese">Steam</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I am not expecting the answer, just an explanition to why this isn't working.

I tried changing the height of the html and body to 100vh and 100%. Tried the same thing on the backgroundMAIN div and main div too. I do not know to to do.

```
    .backgroundMAIN{
        /*background-color: lightgray;*/
        background-color: black;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
     }

    .main{
        /*background-color: beige;*/
        background-color: red;
        height: 100%;
        width: 80%;
        margin-left: 10%;
        margin-right: 10%;
        overflow-wrap: break-word;
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

Comment: I am commenting just to help improve the value of your question ...  My suggestion is instead of putting links to your code, just copy and paste your HTML and CSS into a *code snippet* --  Identified by the `<>` icon in the tool bar when posting/editing.

Comment: @Zak the thing is its big chunks of code, should I edit it anyway?

Comment: Sure .. The snippet tool will automatically make scrollable.  Sometimes too much code is bad when it's a program, but I don't see it being an issue with HTML CSS

Comment: The problem is that you're using `float` and `position: absolute`, which takes the elements out of the flow, meaning that any parent thinks that they have a hight and width of 0. Try to stay away from using those until you're more experienced.

Comment: @RickardElimää how would you suggest I put a div over another div? Right now I tried was using ` postion: abosolute `

Comment: Comments aren't made for chat, but you could use `transform: translate()` on the div you want to overlap, or `margin-bottom: -2rem` on the parent element. Also, `height: 100%` is only suitable if the parent element has any height, but it adapts to its children's height otherwise. So `height: 100%` is mostly setting it's own height to itself, unless other elements are taller.

Comment: @RickardElimää Hey! I know comments aren't made for chatting but I just wanted to say that what you said fixed my problem. The part where you said that I was just setting the height to itself. I removed it on the parent element and it worked! Thank you! :D

Comment: @Kiko Glad I could help out. Happy coding!

Comment: @RickardElimää -- This is perfectly acceptable as an answer ..  Post your edits to the code and explain why it works for OP -- You deserve credit!